# Is CSS inspired from C?

Tags: c, css

Maybe I'm not the first to ask this, but I've searched up and down the stack and I am yet to get an answer to my question. I have learnt CSS, and I also have a basic idea of the C programming language. While learning C, the syntaxes and the way it is coded strongly reminds me of CSS.

For example:

**Comments** both in C and CSS are given within `/*` and `*/`.

**Tasks** to be performed, both in C and CSS are given within curly braces(`{` and `}`)

**Statements** in both C and CSS are **separated**  using semicolons (`;`).

So with these many (maybe more) similarities, I thought C was inspired by CSS. But C seemed to be older than CSS. So my question is, is CSS inspired from C?

Comment: CSS isn't a programming language, so the connection is rather tenuous.  All technological advances in software development draw heavily from previous ideas, though.

Comment: It's hard to come up with a useful new idea in CS without ever having heard of C. Therefore every new idea could be said to be inspired by C.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It is a language but not imperative. Not comparable to C. Most likely the person who created CSS initially was familiar with the C syntax, that is all. If they liked another language, we would have something else.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

If you check the original proposal: https://www.w3.org/People/howcome/p/cascade.html you can see the following quote

> The C-style syntax of the first statement reads: If the document is
>   older than three days, the background color should be pale yellow,
>   else the background color should be white.

Comment: This doesn’t seem to me to indicate inspiration but rather only similarity.

Comment: hmmmmmmmmmmm, well we will have to go ask him. But think we would still be arguing about the definition of "inspired"

Comment: I would recommend clearly stating that it is the *syntax* that is inspired by C syntax. CSS is not a programming language, and the actual meaning of CSS rules is nothing like C.

Comment: im not sure you are right. This early doc has conditional statements, multipliers and uses = rather than the existing : It mentions the lack of variables, but only as a limitation to keep it simple

Comment: Even if we ignore what was eventually standardized, quoting from that document we have: "While a style sheet may look like a procedural program, it lacks many of the constructs of traditional programming languaguages, e.g.: compound statements, variables, and/or. Rather, the style sheets are declarations of constraints." The "style sheets are a declaration of constraints" is the fundamental difference. This is in no way inspired by C. (It's a bit closer to AWK though, but still quite different.)

Comment: yes but as i said, its under 'limitations' implying to me that the reader is expected to perhaps assume that css has those things and it needs to be clarified that they have been deliberately left out. ie its c minus some bits rather than some new things using a similar syntax

Comment: Its interesting that this doc lacks semi-colons and curly braces. I wonder if they come later from ecma script rather than c

Comment: @JamesMcLeod: I think your distinction can be solved semantically: CSS is not inspired by C, but the CSS _syntax_ is in fact inspired by the C _syntax_.

Comment: The 'C-style syntax' in question ( the ternary conditional operator ) never made it to CSS, so although it shows the author had a familiarity with C, it does not show any influence of C in the CSS syntax the question is about - in fact, the selector syntax in CSS is quite the opposite to having single properties that change values based on conditions.

Comment: @pete the op lists a number of similarities and asks 'do these originate with c?' while these things are common in more than one language we can see that css started out as a list of c statements, so the likelyhood is that yes, they are from c